# Make a columheader in a Listview (GridView) collapse dynamically

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, styles

I want to present data in a `ListView` using a `GridView`. Depending on the amount of data that is shown I want to make the columheaders collapse or to be visible.
I tried to acomplish this thus:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowCompact}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But this not working. How can it be done?

Comment: you can try looking in the Output window to see if there is any Binding error notified there. I doubt there should be some Binding error here (related to the actual DataContext you set for the ListView directly or inherited from parent visual).

Comment: @KingKing I have created a ShowCompact property on every level of Binding there was available but the property is not hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine.  A minimal recreation worked without any problems for me:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

View Model:

```
public class ListWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _showCompact;

    public bool ShowCompact
    {
        get { return _showCompact; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _showCompact)
                return;

            _showCompact = value;

            this.OnPropertyChanged("ShowCompact");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.ListWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:StackOverflow">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ListWindowViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowCompact}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"
              Content="Show Compact"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowCompact, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <ListView>
      <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="s:String">
          <s:String>Item 1</s:String>
          <s:String>Item 2</s:String>
          <s:String>Item 3</s:String>
        </x:Array>
      </ListView.ItemsSource>
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Text" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding .}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Length" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Length}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Double-check that you are binding against a public property and raising the necessary change notification events.  It might help if you post the relevant parts of your view model and Xaml.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to prove that "it just works". I checked my bindings once more and found that I had implemented the ShowCompact property on the wrong level after all.